# Change the working directory when debug in emacs gdb?

Tags: emacs, gdb, caffe

As I open emacs and enter :

> M+x gdb
>
> Run gdb (like this):  gdb im=mi
>   /home/qinchen/major/caffe/caffe_gdb/build/tools/caffe

And then input:

> run train --solver=examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt

But it reports :
i

> o.cpp Check failed: fd!=-1. file not
>   found:examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt

I guess if the error is triggered by emacs' current working directory is not in CAFFE_ROOT. Since as I debug in linux terminal in CAFFE_ROOT directory with

> gdb --args build/tools/caffe train
>   --solver=examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt

I can successfully debug this demo.So can anyone help me to set emacs working directory to CAFFE_ROOT when debug in gdb to eliminate the error reported above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple:

```
M+x gdb
gdb -i=mi -cd /home/qinchen/major/caffe/caffe_gdb --args build/tools/caffe train --solver=examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototx
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally find it pretty annoying copying and pasting the absolute path to my executable so I normally just run it this way:

`M+x` then `gdb` and run with the default command: `gdb -i=mi`

Better yet, if you use Projectile, you can do `projectile-run-gdb` (or `C-c p x g`) to run gdb with the project root as the CWD. This way you can just pass: `gdb -i=mi build/tools/caffe`. This is pretty handy for me since my `build` directory is normally in my project root.

If you don't use projectile, when in the gdb interface, doing `pwd` tells you where you are. I just usually have to `cd` once or twice to get to the working directory I'd like to be in. Then just doing `file build/tools/caffe` opens the file for debugging and you're ready to go.

Pasting or editing paths/args into the mini-buffer can be infuriating for me. This way I just run it, change a directory or two, and work with a relative path as I would in the console.